# GRUB shows menu for Ubuntu 20.04 but not for Pop!_OS 22.04

Tags: boot, grub, bootloader, efi, pop-os

I decided to switch to Pop!_OS 22.04 from Ubuntu 20.04, while I'm mentally preparing to switch to Devuan in the future. The GRUB is configurable from Ubuntu as expected, but when I do exactly the same thing on Pop!_OS, then suddenly GRUB menu doesn't change at all.

Pop!_OS 22.04 comes with systemd-boot, which I removed via `bootctl remove`. And then installed `grub`.

The file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` does change after running `update-grub`, but whether I choose `pop` or `ubuntu` from UEFI "boot priority order" menu, it **always** shows GRUB menu which is configured from Ubuntu (not Pop!_OS).

In `/boot/` I have:

```
grub/grub.cfg
```

and

```
efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
efi/EFI/pop/grub.cfg
```

I tried to leave only `pop` folder (remove `ubuntu`), but GRUB just shows me its bash-like interface. So I have to reinstall and update GRUB from Ubuntu (chroot from live CD), since doing this from Pop!_OS doesn't affect anything (for the end user).

I'm using Lenovo Yoga 920-13IKB laptop.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears the reason is, grub hasn't implemented looking for the pop/grub.cfg properly. A workaround that worked for me is just to manually keep the ubuntu/grub.cfg updated with what you want the pop grub menu to do.

see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284787/grub-only-in-shell-mode-wrong-root-and-prefix-set

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: GRUB hasn't implemented or Pop!_OS hasn't implemented? I'm not a friend with grub, but I think it should work with whatever OS you have, but it must be configured properly.

I've fully switched to Pop!_OS about 4 months ago, and I already noticed that it is not all nice and shiny as I imagined. Maybe part of it is that it is based on Ubuntu. Anyway, I switched to rEFInd and it works great so far.